# Consuming API with Laravel Passport

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-passport

I dont understand how to send the token:

```
$response = $client->request('GET', '/api/user', [
'headers' => [
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$accessToken,
],
```

]);

If I have a HTML Form how can I send the token to consume the API?

Thanks

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/passport#consuming-your-api-with-javascript "This Passport middleware will attach a laravel_token cookie to your outgoing responses. This cookie contains an encrypted JWT that Passport will use to authenticate API requests from your JavaScript application. Now, you may make requests to your application's API without explicitly passing an access token."

Comment: But if I am using another app to consume the laravel API passport, how can I send those parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to authenticate in the API first to get the token and then send any other request using that token.

Examples with Curl:

**Authentication first:**

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://laravel-app-with-passport.com/oauth/token",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => "grant_type=password&client_id=".$outhCliendIdGeneratedInLaravelPassport ."&client_secret=".$OuthClientSecretGenerateInLaravelPassport ."&username=". $validLaravelUserName . "&password=" . $validLaravelUserPassword,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);

    $responseInfo = curl_getinfo($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    if ($err) {
        set_error_handler($err);
    } else {

        if ($responseInfo['http_code'] == 200) {

            $_SESSION['TOKEN'] = json_decode($response)->access_token;
            $_SESSION['TOKE_TYPE'] = json_decode($response)->token_type;

        } else {

            set_error_handler("Login to api faild status 403");
            error_log("No login api status 403");

        }
    }
```

**Then, you can send the the token and consume any url in the api:**

```
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => "http://laravel-app-with-passport.com/api/someurl",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
        CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => $method,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => null, // here you can send parameters
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            "accept: application/json",
            "authorization: " . $_SESSION['TOKE_TYPE'] . " " . $_SESSION['TOKEN'] . "",
            "cache-control: no-cache",
            "content-type: application/json",
        ),
    ));

    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    $err = curl_error($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    var_dump($response);
```

Also, as someone said before, you can use instead of curl, Guzzle HTTP Client (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send requests to external app API in PHP, you can use for example **Guzzle HTTP Client** (https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle)